# iPhone SDK - EventKit time zone issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I am having some trouble with adding an event to a calendar in my iPhone app.

I am using the code:

```
EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
EKEvent *event  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
event.title     = self.event.eventTitle;
event.startDate = self.event.startDate;
event.endDate   = self.event.endDate;
event.notes     = self.event.description;

[event setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
NSError *err;   
[eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];
```

which adds an `event` to my calendar just fine. The problem is that my timezone is clearly off. For instance, `self.event.startdate` outputs in the debugger as `012-05-11 20:45:00 +0000`, which is correct.
However, when I look in my calendar, the event was added at **4:45 PM** (not **20:45** or **8:45 PM** as it should be).

When I output the entire event object using po event, I get:

```
EKEvent <0xf853320> {EKEvent <0xf853320> {title = Tuesday Night Lights!; location = (null); calendar = (null); alarms = (null); URL = (null); lastModified = (null); timeZone = EST (GMT-05:00) offset -18000}; location = (null); startDate = 2012-05-11 20:45:00 +0000; endDate = 2012-05-11 21:45:00 +0000; allDay = 0; floating = 0; recurrence = (null); attendees = (null)}
```

Here the `startDate` reads correctly too. I am located in **EST** timezone (as is my phone), **so how can I get my code to add the event to my calendar at 8:45 PM?**

Any thoughts would be very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

The event is added at the correct time. It is just a matter of showing the time with the correct time-zone corrections. I have found that this solved my problem:

Instead of writing it like this:

```
NSLog(@"startDate: %@", [startDate description]);
```

Write it like this:

```
NSLog(@"startDate: %@", [startDate descriptionWithLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]]);
```

Hope this could help you to solve your problem.